# Keras "Shapes must be of equal rank" error when trying to slice tensor with another tensor

Tags: keras

Building off some of the other questions I've asked, I'm trying to define a custom loss function that allows me to slice the contents of an input tensor using the contents of another tensor:

```py
def innerLoss(z):
    y_pred = z[0] 
    patch_x = z[1][0]
    patch_y = z[1][1]
    patch_true = y_pred[patch_y:patch_y+10, patch_x:patch_x+10, 0]
    return 0

originalInputs = Input(shape=(128, 128, 1))
featureInputs = Input(shape=(2,), dtype="int64")
originalOutputs = Input(shape=(128, 128, 1))
loss = Lambda(innerLoss)([originalOutputs, featureInputs])
outerModel = Model(inputs=[originalInputs, featureInputs], outputs=loss)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```py
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0
    From merging shape 1 with other shapes. for 'lambda_3/strided_slice_2/stack_1' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [2], [2], [].
```

Here, `featureInputs` will consist of a pair of coordinates telling us where to begin slicing the image in `originalInputs`.

Comment: You are not considering the fact that the first dimension denotes the batch size. To understand what I am saying, print shapes of `y_pred`, `patch_x` and `patch_y` inside `innerLoss` before `patch_true`. You will find out what the problem is.

Comment: Ah, I see. So i need to change `patch_x = z[1][0]` to `patch_x = z[1][0,0]` and same for `path_y` (for batch size 1). But now I get a Datatype error: `Value passed to parameter 'begin' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64`. Why would this be? I defined `featureInputs` to have type `int32`...

Comment: I don't know why it is cast to float. Just cast them back to int: `patch_y = K.cast(patch_y, 'int32')` and `patch_x = K.cast(patch_x, 'int32)`. The `K` is a reference to backend in Keras: `from keras import backend as K`.